# Why does my PPA not have any signing key?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, pgp

Somehow [one](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecozy-team/+archive/ubuntu/cozy) of the PPAs I maintain (belongs to a team) does not have a signing key.

[image]

<sup>No signing key listed here</sup>

Why does the PPA not have a signing key and how to fix this?

Note that I can successfully use the PPA in Ubuntu 21.04, and also, I do have GPG keys configured with [my launchpad account](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1).

Comment: Really the GPG key exists, but not listed on launchpad PPA page. The fingerprint is 16946AB256F1A0884B5CE3925DD7991B3AA59025 . See https://pastebin.com/raw/ez2j76Qz - it is output from 21.04 docker image. [Cozy Daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cozy-team/+archive/ubuntu/cozy-daily) faces the same issue.

Comment: @N0rbert And the same key is imported when I add the PPA.

Comment: @archisman-panigrahi As I've replied on the GitHub issue, I was able to resolved the issue (thanks to n0rbert), but if you manage to list the `signing key / fingerprint` on Cozy PPA page, it would help others. Many thanks for quick replies.